# Python one-liner to print text converted from ASCII numbers?

Tags: python, ascii, code-snippets, idioms, ordinal

The following command print text from it's ASCII representative.

```
python -c "print unichr(72)"
```

E.g.

```
[user@linux ~]$ python -c "print unichr(72)"
H
[user@linux ~]$
```

But this is only for a single character. If I have an ASCII string, let say `72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100` for `Hello World`, is it possible to convert it in Python in one line?

I've been trying the following commands but it didn't work.

```
[user@linux ~]$ python -c "print unichr(72)" "unichr(72)"
H
[user@linux ~]$
```

...

```
[user@linux ~]$ python -c "print unichr(72) unichr(72)"      
  File "<string>", line 1
    print unichr(72) unichr(72)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[user@linux ~]$
```

...

```
[user@linux ~]$ python -c "print unichr(72)(72)"         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
[user@linux ~]$
```

Comment: You still need to use valid Python syntax, even with `-c`.

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. What is the valid Python syntax for this case? I'm new to Python and still learning (self learning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ python -c 'print "".join(unichr(i) for i in (72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100))'
Hello World
```

#### How it works

This generates a list of unicode characters:

```
>>> [unichr(i) for i in (72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100)]
[u'H', u'e', u'l', u'l', u'o', u' ', u'W', u'o', u'r', u'l', u'd']
```

This combines the list of characters into a string:

```
>>> ''.join(unichr(i) for i in (72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100))
u'Hello World'
```

#### Python3 Version

`unichr` no longer exists in python3.  Instead, use:

```
>>> print("".join(chr(i) for i in (72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100)))
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 python -c 'print "".join(unichr(int(c)) for c in "72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100".split(" "))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the `unichr()` calls with a `+` or `,` will work.

Example:`python -c "print unichr(72)+unichr(73),unichr(65)"` prints `HI A`

You can see `+` concatenates and `,` adds a space in between.

So, you can use the `+` operator between the `unichr()` function calls